# List holders and tokens for an ERC-721 contract

Tags: web3js, events, erc-721

Given a contract, I want to map the holders to their token ids.

For example, the contract [`0xFBeef911Dc5821886e1dda71586d90eD28174B7d`](https://etherscan.io/address/0xfbeef911dc5821886e1dda71586d90ed28174b7d) is an ERC-721 contract for [KnownOriginDigitalAsset](https://etherscan.io/token/0xfbeef911dc5821886e1dda71586d90ed28174b7d). Etherscan offers a [nice interface](https://etherscan.io/token/0xfbeef911dc5821886e1dda71586d90ed28174b7d#balances) that maps the holders with the amount of tokens they own. I'd like to create something similar, but instead of the total tokens owned, I want to show the list of tokens.

Each time an ERC-721 token is transferred, it triggers a `Transfer` event. A first approach is to listen to all past and future `Transfer` events and use them to create and update my map of holders to token ids.

I synchronized my node running `parity` with the default options (note that the default pruning strategy is `fast`). Then, I run the following script

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546/'))
const erc721abi = require('./ERC721.json')
const contractAddress = '0xf26A23019b4699068bb54457f32dAFCF22A9D371'
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc721abi, contractAddress)
const acc = []
contract.events.Transfer(
  {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'},
  (err, data) => !err && acc.push(data)
)
console.log(acc.length)
```

At the time of writing, the script emits 31 `Transfer` events, while Etherscan states there are 81 holders. (Note: minting a token emits a `Transfer` event as well.)

Is this the correct approach? Should I synchronize the blockchain using `parity --purge=archive` to see all events?

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9188

Comment: Thanks @SimondelaRouviere. Yes, it should be related. At the beginning I thought that `warp` would sync all data, but his is [not true](https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity?at=5bdb48c22cb7054a8cf4de36). Plus, there are issues with different versions of Parity (I went from beta, to stable, to another beta, and it's still not able to fully sync)

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

We are considering how to query the Ethereum blockchain using the Web3 JS API to collect events, summarizing this data to find the most recent recipient of each ERC-721 token.

Running your own infrastructure (Geth / Parity) is outside the scope of this question.

## Answer

This answer uses Node.js. First, create this `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721": "^2.0.0-rc1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  }
}
```

This includes web3js and the ABI for ERC-721 from 0xcert, the reference implementation.

Run `npm install`.

Next, create `query.js`:

```
const CONTRACT_ACCOUNT = "0xE9e3F9cfc1A64DFca53614a0182CFAD56c10624F";
const CONTRACT_START = 6645906;
const INFURA_KEY = "55397e793412497fb349e0ff77f154f2";

const Web3 = require('web3'); // Use web3@1.0.0-beta.36+ https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1916
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/' + INFURA_KEY));
const erc721 = require("@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/build/erc721.json").ERC721;
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc721.abi, CONTRACT_ACCOUNT);
var idToOwner = {};

contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {fromBlock: CONTRACT_START, toBlock: CONTRACT_START+60000}).then(events => {
  events.forEach(event => {
    idToOwner[event.returnValues._tokenId] = event.returnValues._to
  });
  console.log(idToOwner);
});
```

This is a testing key for Infura, you're welcome. Or to Infura, I'm sorry.

## Discussion

Here's a few notes I learned working on this answer. All of these are bugs/intricacies that apply to the Infura service, but they may also apply to other services:

- Using `CONTRACT_START` rather than starting at block zero halves the runtime.
- If at all possible, consider using adding a `filter: {from: 0x...}` parameter. The is a speedup of 10x for the same data.
- The request must be broken into 60,000 blocks at a time and then repeated to avoid timing out.

The contract address below is for Su Squares. Luckily, we are able to use a `from:` filter for our use case and this allows us to query Infura all in one pass.

Comment: See also a demo implementing this at https://github.com/fulldecent/contract-scanner/